# Laravel scope with method Model::all() not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
$orders = Order::all();
$count = $orders->count();
$ordersActive = $orders->during()->count(); //this not working, I get undefined method during
```

I have defined the scope in the model Order:

```
public function scopeDuring($query)
{
    $query->whereNotIn('stat', [1,2,3,4]);
}
```

I get undefined method `during`.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a `return` in your scopeDuring filter.

Comment: This not help me. I whatever get error `Method during does not exist.`

Comment: Change it to `$orders = Order::during()->all();`

Comment: And? How I can get then orders without scope durring?

Comment: `Order::all()`, have you read the docs?

Comment: Lol, I want 1 query in all with during, but not 2 quires..

Comment: @Bommber In one query you cannot get with scope results and without scope result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code 
If you want to get all orders use this

```
$orders = Order::all();
```

If you want to get orders with scope use this

```
$ordersActive = Order::during()->get();
```

And after that, you will get the count by these queries

```
$count = $orders->count();
$ordersActiveCount = $ordersActive->count();
```

Comment: 2 queries.. I want 1 query :))

Comment: Thanks but what is the problem with 2 queries? It will not take more times 
 to load because we have retrieved all results with **$orders** and **$ordersActive**.

Comment: No there is nothing like two queries are not good. It's not good when you are using the same query two times. But here both queries have different results  so this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You have alredy get the collection, so you cannot use the method of the model. Instead of this you should do this:

```
$count = Order::count();
$ordersActive = Order::during()->count();
```